# Unable to understand , how value is computed when pointer to pointer is subtracted by array of pointer

Tags: c

```
static int a[]={0,1,2,3,4};
static int *p[]={a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
int **ptr = p;

ptr++;
printf("\n%d %d %d",ptr-p,*ptr-p,**ptr);

Output -> 1 1 1
```

I am not able to understand , how expression "ptr-p" is yielding value 1 in all cases(I understand working of **ptr).

Comment: `*ptr-p` is a type error.

Comment: `ptr-p` is 1 because `ptr == p + 1`.  It's right there in your code:  `ptr++` adds 1 to `ptr`.  Of course, it's scaled by `sizeof(*ptr)`, but the inverse is performed on the result of the subtraction.

Comment: @melpomene Nope it isn't .

Comment: @codeFreak Why not?

Comment: @codeFreak It's an error.  Subtracting pointers of incompatible types produces a compile-time error.

Comment: @TomKarzes Agree with your explanation of ptr+1 but unable to get why there is no impact on value due to subtraction with address p ?

Comment: @melpomene It is compiling fine with gcc version 5.1.0.

Comment: @codeFreak When you subtract two pointers, it gives the number of pointed-to elements between them.  In terms of bytes, it divides the byte difference by the number of bytes in the pointed-to type.  So if `p2 == p1 + i` for some integer `i`, then `p2 - p1 == i`.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: @codeFreak Are you compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99`? Also, compilers are not required to diagnose all errors (but `-pedantic` makes gcc print all messages required by the standard).

Comment: @melpomene Nope with gcc -g -wall .

Comment: @codeFreak gcc 7.3.0 gives a hard compile-time error for the posted code.  It does not produce an object file.  Check your source file, you must have made a mistake.

Comment: @codeFreak Lowercase `-w` *disables* warnings. Try my options.

Comment: with gcc 6.3 it is impossible to compile that code even with "-w" without adding a cast for `*ptr-p` and if I add a cast this produced 1 -4 1 (my CPU has 32 bits)

Comment: options do not matter - all standards and -w produce the same error. https://godbolt.org/z/r79zZo - you can try yourself

Comment: @codeFreak maybe you compile another file and that causes your confusion. Or you get the error and you keep executing old exe file - from the successful compilation?

Comment: @TomKarzes Please can you elaborate your answer more , I am unable to get.

Comment: @codeFreak I think what you really need is a tutorial on C pointer arithmetic.  A quick web search turned up [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm).  If you read and understand it, then you should understand your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `ptr - p` - when you initialized `ptr`, it gets the value of `p`. Both of them are essentially pointers to pointers to integers - `int **` (I believe that you understand that arrays can be treated as pointers in some cases, including this one; not in all cases though...). Since you incremented that value of `ptr`, its value is greater than `p` by exactly 1, thus `ptr - p = 1`.
- `**ptr` - since `ptr` was incremented, it now points to the second item of `p` (i.e `p[1]`), which is `a+1`. By performing double-dereferencing you eventually get: `**ptr = *p[1] = *(a+1) = a[1] = 1`

While I can explain the first and last result (`ptr-p`, `**ptr`), I can't understand how the middle result (`*ptr - p`) even compiles - it's an arithmetical operation between 2 different types (`int *`, `int **`) so the compiler raises an error.

Hope that at least the first part makes sense...